# How to change the background of a view that is not on screen?

Tags: java, android, gridview, imageview

I am having a problem. I have a gridView, where if you tap on an item, the backgrounds of other items in the gridview change. But, if any item is not on screen, but in the scroll bar, the app crashes with a NullPointerException error, which i am assuming is because the imageview of the item is not on screen.

here is the gridview and imageadapter

```
<GridView
            android:id="@+id/gridView1"
            android:layout_width="400dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@drawable/redback"
            android:columnWidth="50dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_above="@+id/bbClear"
            android:numColumns="auto_fit"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:stretchMode="none" >
        </GridView>
```

and the image adapter:

```
    // Constructor
    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mThumbIds[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        imageView.setId(mThumbIds[position]);
        //imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER);
        imageView.setPadding(getPixels(3), getPixels(3), getPixels(3), getPixels(3));
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(getPixels(40), getPixels(40)));

        //imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.greentwo);
        return imageView;
    }
    private int getPixels(int dipValue){//because you shouldnt use pixels. dip all the way.
        Resources r = mContext.getResources();
        int px = (int)TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dipValue, 
        r.getDisplayMetrics());
        return px;
}


}
```

the actual error come from the line

```
 v = parent.getChildAt(i);
```

in the onClick method, where i is the position.

what can I do to either:

avoid having a scrollbar appear on smaller screens

or allow backgrounds to be changed of views not on screen.

Comment: Where is the line that causes the NullPointerException?  I take it that happens in `onListItemClicked` but you haven't shown that method.  Not all views exist in the grid view.  Only those that are at least partially on the screen exist.  When they leave the screen, they're added to a stack of views to be converted.  You aren't using the `convertView` in `getView` which is inefficient.  You should consider reusing the convertView.

Comment: Another thing you can do is not use the `getPixels` method .. it's completely unnecessary for fixed dp values.  Instead, put an entry in your dimens.xml file called `image_view_padding` with a value of `3dp`.  Then used `mContext.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.image_view_padding)` and it will give you back an `int` for the number of pixels without you having to do any conversion.

Comment: theres a lot in the item clicked method, but the part that crashes the app is v = parent.getChildAt(i); where i is the position. how do I use a convertView?